# need a details of foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I am adding some records in the child table (foreign key col) where values are [1,2,3,4,5,6] and in the parent table (foreign key referenced col) values exist [1,2,3,4] so at the insertion, the query won't execute and throw some error because reference for value 5 and 6 doesn't exist in parent table.
I wanted from MySQL to return the values/data due to which foreign key constraint fails.
**Example** : "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xyz`.`pqr`, CONSTRAINT `***_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`***`) REFERENCES `***` (`***`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) **for values [5,6]**".

**In Short**
I just wanted to know due to which row/record/data foreign key constraint fails to display this to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say there are two entities namely `User` and `Roles`. A `User` must have at least one role. Thre is an attribute called `role_id` in the `User` table which is referencing to `id` attribute in role table.

Roles are already defined and one shall select an appropriate role for a user while creating a user.

Let us say you received the following error while creating user -

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sample_db`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_role1` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

The error above indicates that there is no `Role` available for the  `role_id` which you are mentioning while creating a user.